# How many imbrication in an IMAP search query

Tags: python, email, imap

I'm trying to make complex IMAP search query using bare python `imaplib`.

The query is pretty much simple I have a list of emails and I'm trying to query all messages with thoses adresses.

A simple query may look like this :

```
[
  ['OR',
    ['FROM', 'email1@domain.com'],
    ['OR',
      ['FROM', 'email2@domain.com'],
      ['FROM', 'email3@domain.com']
]]]
```

But when I began to make this kind of query with large set of addresses (more thant 5) I get :

```
SEARCH command error: BAD [b'Command Argument Error. 12']
```

Does the IMAP protocol have such limitation ? Maybe because of the complexity of the query ? Or is the max imbrication layer ?

My references or :

- IMAP rfc : https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3501.html
- Python `imaplib` library : https://docs.python.org/3/library/imaplib.html

Comment: There is no such limitation of the protocol, but most servers have very simple or limited search parsers.  When using complex OR though, putting the two conditions in () sometimes helps  OR (FROM …) OR (FROM … ) (FROM …).  However, it may be better to just to send multiple search commands….

Comment: I’m also not familiar with the word `imbrication` for programming. Is this the french translation of ‘recursion’?

Comment: The server parsers aren't great, but I have problems believing that a server manages to parse a single OR and hits a complexity ceiling at two.

Answer (score 0):

IMAP Query limitations may be on your email server side.
This is independent of imaplib.

You can try to use IMAP query builder from my lib: https://github.com/ikvk/imap_tools

It can helps to build such queries much easier.

For example, i have successfully try to do this at (YANDEX, ZIMBRA, OUTLOOK, GOOGLE):

```
from imap_tools import MailBox, OR
with MailBox('imap.mail.com').login('test@mail.com', 'pwd') as mailbox:
    for msg in mailbox.fetch(OR(from_=['1@a','2@a','3@a','4@a','5@a','6@a','hello@ya.ru'])):
        print(msg.date)
```